# How to center a “position: absolute” element in IE 9,10,11

Tags: css

How to center a “position: absolute” element in IE 9, 10, 11, my example do not work in Internet Explorer. Also this "position: absolute; left:50%; margin-left:-20px;" ,manner will not suit me, as the layout is responsive.

```
.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    right: 0;   
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;       
}

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Html code please, and fiddle if possible

Comment: center the div in the page.. check link. http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/1/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;   
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;   //specify all including bottom:0
    margin: auto;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;       
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fx3qs/)

Comment: @zuke: that's nice :)

Comment: @DominiqueAlexandre Gravedigging - max-width looks like it works with `width: 100%`

Comment: A max-width is better than a fixed width indeed.

Comment: just tested out @DominiqueAlexandre answer and max-width worked for me, but also if you want to retain the max-width, you could still use both for a fall back, thanks !

Comment: Adding the left:0 right:0 makes no sense but it works. Glad there is stack overflow

Comment: The KEY seems to be the margin auto; Without that, on IE11, seems to be centered horizontally, but stuck at the top. Interesting!

Answer (score 3):

Just give it a fixed width and height and remove top:150px

Comment: You can add width and hight with 100%, if u have no specific size. Works as well in IE.

Comment: @sircrom Wow I've spent hours googling this issue, never thought it would be so simple to fix!

Answer (score 3):

I just struggled with this myself, and the specific key for me was changing the `max-width` property to be a `width` property.  Adding a max-width doesn't break it, but it relies on the `width` property in IE, apparently, where in Firefox it worked with just the max-width set.

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Oh, I just now saw Dominique's comment!  D'oh!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It works fine here [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wac8Z/1/)

```
.box{
position: absolute;
top: 150px;
right: 0;   
left: 0;
margin: auto;   
border: 2px solid red;    
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to set a bottom property ([even in IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531140(v=vs.85).aspx)), to center that element horizontally.

However, if you wanted to vertically center the element, you would need the bottom property in conjunction with an auto margin for top and bottom.

If your element will only center horizontally with "bottom" set to 0, then there is something conflicting in your code forcing you to use that property. I have seen this happen before in Bootstraps Ecosystem when not applying the proper hierarchy of container --> row  and so on.